# GEE, Error generating chart: User memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, memory

I want to make a scatter plot between a list of NDVI values and LST values. I've tried it all. I think is a lack of best practices in my code.

Here's my script:

```
var LST = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1")
var NDVI_Unmasked = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2")
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
      [-58.27563501908931, -16.339490377818237],
      [-58.27563501908931, -18.727789465180184],
      [-55.50708033158931, -18.727789465180184],
      [-55.50708033158931, -16.339490377818237]
]])

var NDVI_Unmasked = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2")
  .select('NDVI')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'))
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.clip(geometry)
  })
  .mean()

var NDVI_mask = NDVI_Unmasked.gt(-32767)
var self_NDVI_Mask = NDVI_mask.selfMask()

var LST = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1")
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'))
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.clip(geometry)
      .multiply(0.02)
      .subtract(273.15)
      .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start'])
  })
  .mean()
  .updateMask(self_NDVI_Mask)
var LST_mask = LST.gt(-273.14)

var self_LST_Mask = LST_mask.selfMask()

var NDVI = NDVI_Unmasked.updateMask(self_LST_Mask)
var pixelValsNDVI = NDVI.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 0.02,
  maxPixels: 10e11,
  bestEffort: true
})

var pixelValsLST = LST.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 0.02,
  maxPixels: 10e11,
  bestEffort: true
})
var x = ee.List(pixelValsNDVI.get('NDVI'))
var y = ee.List(pixelValsLST.get('LST_Day_1km'))

var zip = x.zip(y)
  .distinct()

var unzip = zip.unzip()

var x1 = unzip.get(0)
var y1 = unzip.get(1)

var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({
  array: y1,
  axis: 0,
  xLabels: x1
})
print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a80f874d90cb03bebf3acea8e79ba23e

Comment: Could you please add the code to the question body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs out of memory because you run `reduceRegion()`, extracting a list of all pixels within an area of tens of thousands of square kilometers, at a scale of 2 cm. You are trying to put `10e11` (you end up with `maxPixels` since you use `bestEffort`) into a list and run out of memory as a result.  Maybe you mixed up the unit of the scale parameter in `reduceRegion()`? It's in meters. Your imagery has a scale of 1km, so there's no need to have the scale smaller than that.

I would approach this differently, not try to chart all pixels, but a random sample?

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
      [-58.27563501908931, -16.339490377818237],
      [-58.27563501908931, -18.727789465180184],
      [-55.50708033158931, -18.727789465180184],
      [-55.50708033158931, -16.339490377818237]
]])

var NDVI = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2")
  .select('NDVI')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'))
  .mean()
    
var LST = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1")
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'))
  .mean()
  .multiply(0.02)
  .subtract(273.15)

var means = NDVI.updateMask(NDVI.gt(-32767))
  .addBands(
    LST.updateMask(LST.gt(-273.14))
  )
  .clip(geometry)

var samples = means.sample({
  region: geometry, 
  scale: 1000, 
  numPixels: 1000 // Control how many pixels you want to sample
})


var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: samples, 
  xProperty: 'NDVI', 
  yProperties: 'LST_Day_1km'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'Temperature Vegetation Dryness Index',
  colors: ['cf513e'],
  hAxis: {
    title: 'NDVI',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'LST',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
  pointSize: 4,
  lineSize: 0,
  dataOpacity: 0.4,
  legend: {position: 'none'}
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/efdfab5de7d4c5ddb6d7baa4076f6301

Comment: Changing the scale worked!!!!!!!!! I just copied from the properties of the modis image collection and didnt have caution to see the units. Ive tried sampling it, but it is importante to get the whole image. Thanks so much.